# Renaming Java class with Maven Archetype

Tags: java, spring-boot, rename, maven-archetype

Is it possible to rename a java class using Maven?
I'm using the **Maven Archetype** to generate new projects based on my model. I can set a new groupId, artifactId, and packages for each new project.

This is the current **pom.xml** inside target.

```xml
<groupId>${groupId}</groupId>
<artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
<version>${version}</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

So, when I want to create a project **Banana** (artifactId) inside **com.foo** (groupId) , it's pretty possible. All I need to do is run: `mvn archetype:generate (...arguments like groupId, artifactId, version)`

It will generate a new project based on my archetype, renaming its packages, groupId, artifactId. But I **also** want to rename some **java classes**, thus:

**ArchetypeApplication.java** should be renamed to **BananaApplication.java**!

Is there some way to do that?

Comment: Those are sample files generated by a dumb template. Just refactor them in your ide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only specify a class name if the archetype supports this feature. For example: [zk-archetype-theme](https://jarcasting.com/archetypes/org.zkoss/zk-archetype-theme/) defines the "theme-listener-class" property for this.